# Access i18n values from vuejs component

Tags: vue.js, highcharts, internationalization

I use i18n to provide multilingual support to an application, I'd like the charts I provide with highcharts to have the same behaviour.

```html
<i18n>
{
  "fr": {
    "test": "en fançais"
  },
  "en": {
    "test": "in english"
  } 
}
</i18n>

<template>
    <highcharts :options="options"></highcharts>
</template>

<script>
import '@/plugins/highcharts.js'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      options: {
        chart: {
          type: 'bar'
        },
        series: [{
          name: $t('test'),
          data: [1.0, 0.3, 0],
          color: '#beab9d'
        }],
        xAxis: {
          categories: ["1", "2", "3"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

But when building the application, I got :

```
'$t' is not defined
```

There is a way to access i18n values from the script part of a component ?

Comment: `$t` is not a global variable, it's scoped to `Vue` so use `this.$t`

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect !